# Can't use Descendants() or Elements() with xmlns

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I'm new to working with XML, and I've encountered a weird problem while trying to get a specific tag from a spring.net configuration file. After trying to narrow down the problem with a test xml file, I found out that applying the following code:

```
List<XElement> nodes = xmlFile.Descendants("B").ToList();
```

provides a non-empty list with the following file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<A fakeAttribute="aaa">
  <B id="DbProvider"/>
</A>
```

but provides an empty string with the following file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<A xmlns="aaa">
  <B id="DbProvider"/>
</A>
```

The only difference between the files being the attribute.

I can't imagine an explanation for this. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to search for tags in that namespace:

```
XNamespace ns = "aaa";

xmlFile.Descendants(ns + "B").ToList()
```

Comment: Thanks! That did the trick - but also opened the way to another problem. I can obtain descendants named "B", for example, but cannot obtain descendants named "db:provider" (not by using "db" nor "db:provider"), which is sadly exactly what I need to do.

Comment: db is listed as a different namespace. My bad.

Comment: @Tomata If you want to ignore namespaces you can write something like: `var lst = doc.Descendants().Where(p => p.Name.LocalName == "B").ToList();`

Answer (score 10):

Just for completeness sake:

```
var lst = doc.Descendants("{aaa}B").ToList();
```

(what the other told is correct, but I wanted to give another option :-) )

For ultra completeness-sake, if you want to search ignoring the namespace:

```
var lst = doc.Descendants().Where(p => p.Name.LocalName == "B").ToList();
```

Answer (score 7):

You should specify the namespace when querying for the elements.

You can use the [GetDefaultNamespace method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.getdefaultnamespace.aspx) to avoid hard-coding it. It's also useful if you don't know what it is ahead of time.

Example:

```
var ns = xmlFile.GetDefaultNamespace();
var nodes = xmlFile.Descendants(ns + "B").ToList();
```

Comment: In one case, .GetDefaultNamespace didn't work because the XML schema author wasn't using xmlns but rather xmlns:foo. You can use: var ns = xDoc.Root.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("foo");